# React Native map "Undefined" is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from API
but. I'm getting this error [**Error Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDuLw.png).

Here is my code.

```js
const [datas, setDatas] = useState(" ");

const res = async () => {
 const response = await axios.get("http://hasanadiguzel.com.tr/api/kurgetir");
 setDatas(response.data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri);
};

datas.map((item) => {
 return (
  <KurCard
   title={item.Isim}
   alis={item.BanknoteBuying}
   satis={item.BanknoteSelling}
  />
 );
});
```

How can I solve this?

I'm trying to `map()` **datas**, because I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Hi @n00b,

The data that `datas` is initially being set to an empty string, which does not have a map method. First, you need an empty array instead of an empty string`useState([])`. Now you can `map`.

```js
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

const res = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://hasanadiguzel.com.tr/api/kurgetir');
  setDatas(response.data.TCMB_AnlikKurBilgileri);
};

{datas.length > 0 &&
  datas.map((item) => {
    return <KurCard title={item.Isim} alis={item.BanknoteBuying} satis={item.BanknoteSelling}/>
  })
}
```

> make sure you data. it has a length greater than 0 before trying to map over it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API request is valid, you would need to actually return something from the component itself and not just the array:

```
return datas.map((item) => {return <KurCard title={item.Isim} alis={item.BanknoteBuying} satis={item.BanknoteSelling}/>})
```